# sqlAlchemy Row Count from Results

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Having recently upgraded sqlAlchemy and Python to 3.8, this code no longer works to get a row count from search results, via the sqlAlchemy ORM. It seems the use of _saved_cursor._result.rows has been depreciated. (Error: AttributeError: 'LegacyCursorResult' object has no attribute '_saved_cursor')

```
def get_clients(db, status):
    clients = Table("clients", db.metadata, autoload=True)
    qry = clients.select().where(clients.c.status == status)
    res = qry.execute()
    rowcount = len(res._saved_cursor._result.rows)
    return rowcount
```

We have this very ugly code that works, but this way has to loop through all the results to get the count.

```
def get_clients(db, status):
    clients = Table("clients", db.metadata, autoload=True)
    qry = clients.select().where(clients.c.status == status)
    res = qry.execute()
    rowcount = 0
    for row in res:
        rowcount += 1
    return rowcount
```

Without using raw sql, what is the most efficient means to get the row count using sqlAlchemy ORM?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the func method from sqlAlchemy, and to render the results as scalar.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, func

def get_clients(db, status):
    clients = Table("clients", db.metadata, autoload=True)
    qry = select([func.count()]).select_from(clients).where(clients.c.status == status)
    row_count = qry.execute().scalar()
    return row_count
```